# copy and delete files using group policy with schedule?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I'm currently using group policy to copy files to other computers and to delete I have to manualy open policy and change from "update" to "delete".
Is it possible to scheduled deletion on specific date?
Or maybe somehow to set up so that my file is created on on specific date and deleted on specific date on computers?